# Bind DDNS change receiving `update failed: NOTAUTH`, how to fix that authorization issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ddns

I have the following zone definition:

```
zone "madetoorder.software" {
  type master;
  file "/var/lib/bind/example.com.zone";
  allow-transfer { trusted-servers; };
  check-names warn;
  update-policy {
    grant local-ddns zonesub any;
    grant letsencrypt_wildcard. name _acme-challenge.example.com. txt;
  };
  max-journal-size 2M;
};
```

As shown, it is expected to allow me to add and remove sub-domains (a.k.a. `foo.example.com`) using `nsupdate`. I tried the following but I'm getting a `NOTAUTH` error:

```
$ sudo nsupdate
> local 165.232.146.181
> zone madetoorder.software
> update delete ve-vlc.madetoorder.software.
> send
NOTAUTH
> update add ve-vlc.madetoorder.software. 60 A 165.232.146.181
> send
NOTAUTH
> quit
```

As we can see, the `send` command fails with a `NOTAUTH`.

I know the `local-ddns` key is loaded successfully since when I try without `sudo` I get the following error:

```
$ nsupdate -l
19-Apr-2022 21:50:16.831 open: //run/named/session.key: permission denied
can't read key from //run/named/session.key: permission denied
```

Looking at the file, it does look like a valid key. Just as expected.

Also, the `letsencrypt` changes to a TXT field work as expected. So what is wrong in:

```
grant local-ddns zonesub any
```

*Note:*

*As shown in the zone definition, the .zone file is under `/var/lib/bind`. And the directory is owned by `root:bind` with permissions `-rwxrwxr-x`. The file itself has permissions `-rw-------`. So `named` (which runs as `bind`) has access to the files.*

Comment: "So named (which runs as bind) has access to the files." It is the user under which you run `nsupdate` that can't read the file due to permissions. Plus it is a bit strange to put the key in`/run` as this is an ephemeral directory that will disapperar on reboot.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The `local-ddns` key is special in that it gets generated by named on startup. At least, that's how it works under Ubuntu. It works while running. If you restart named, it gets regenerated again. So it's not necessary to keep that key across boots and can therefore reside under `/run`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.

I restarted `named`.

I'm not too sure what is happening. It looks like it is running:

```
$ systemctl status named
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-20 14:25:48 UTC; 9h ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
   Main PID: 2334296 (named)
      Tasks: 14 (limit: 9508)
     Memory: 44.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             └─2334296 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind
```

But I can't access anything. It took me a little time to notice that the system was actually *dead*.

When I test using `dig @ns1.example.com www.example.com` it fails when it's in that state. Yet the UDP port is open and as shown above, the status says OKAY (the bullet point is green in my console).

I hope this helps someone else because it is a strange state.